# Limit returned by MS Access query, but calculate all of the rows in query or table

Tags: ms-access

I've got a query in a MS Access database that returns about 100 - 200 lines, which is perfect and exactly what it's supposed to do. However, now the end-user would like to see a summary of the last +/- 15 lines and the totals of the lines that aren't being displayed.

I discovered that Access has a feature top values does this, however if I do this for this specific case it only calculates the totals of the rows that are being displayed. I've also tried to essentially duplicate the query and limit one of them, which partially works. It returns the correct lines, but it seems I can only calculate with values from one query.

Is there any way, to accomplish what I'm trying to do or should I just tell the end-user(s) not to print the first x amount of pages of the report?

Kind regards,

Niek

EDIT: 
Currently I have the following query:

```
SELECT [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].DagrapportCivielId, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].PartijID, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].PartijJaar, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].DatumProef, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].Partijnummer, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].Werknummer, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].BrekerID, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].Projectdag, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].ton, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].ProductID, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[Conclusie Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[Voldoet algemeen ja/nee], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[Conclusie Verklaard], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[Voldoet Verklaard ja/nee], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste7, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse7 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse7, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste11, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse11 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse11, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste12, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse12 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse12, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste16, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse16 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse16, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste18, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse18 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse18, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste25, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse25 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse25, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste45, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse45 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse45, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste77, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse77 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse77, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].Claatste105, [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].[ToetsLaatstse105 Algemeen], [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].ToetsLaatstse105 FROM [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting] LEFT JOIN [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16] ON [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting].DagrapportCivielId = [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16].DagrapportCivielId LIMIT 15;
```

But this won't let me calculate the sum of, for example, ToetsLaatstse7 Algemeen.

Comment: Please standardize your table/field names: read this: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/standards/tables_fields.php.

Have you tried Select Top 15 records from your table sort sortfield dsc/asc??

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips, it's definitely going to be a project for next time, but right now we just need to show the database to the authorized organisation. 
That said, I did indeed tried to use the TOP statement, but that only the top 15 rows are counted which messes up the totals.

Comment: what is the unique ID in your result set?

Comment: DagrapportCivielId is the unique ID both in table(s) and the query.

Comment: If you can create a new statement that returns the data you're looking for (`Count(PartijID), Sum(PartijJaar)`, or however), and name those new fields the same as your original query `(Select Count(PartijID) as PartijID`, etc), then UNION that to your other query, get it ordered so that record shows up at the top - then your summary of the whole table is always the first record returned

Comment: I will get back to you tomorrow as there's an even more urgent problem happening begging for my attention.

Comment: @Acantud Your suggestion worked for me indeed. Is there any way I can mark your comment as answer for future reference?

Comment: @niek_k That's great, thanks for coming back and giving the update - I'll add my comment as an answer if you'd like to accept.  Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create a new SQL statement that returns the data you're looking for, e.g. (Count(PartijID), Sum(PartijJaar), or however), and name those new fields the same as your original query (Select Count(PartijID) as PartijID, etc), then UNION that to your other query, get it ordered so that record shows up at the top - then your summary of the whole table is always the first record returned.

Answer (score 0):

In your sql query you can use

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS .... LIMIT 15;
```

The query will return you 15 rows of result, and one more data containing the total number of result you were supposed to have without LIMIT clause.

More info : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html .

Comment: If I'm not mistaken TOP does the same as LIMIT and does not work in my case. 
I tried adding LIMIT instead, but Access throws an error at me telling that it's not a valid keyword.

Comment: What's the sql query you are using ?

Comment: I edited the starting post as it's too long to post as a comment.

Comment: Using SELECT TOP 15 rest_of_the_query works, but leaves me with incorrect totals. 

This article confirms the lack of the LIMIT keyword in Access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107690/how-to-use-limit-in-query-of-ms-access-2007

Comment: Seems like you cannot use LIMIT in Access... then I dont know, I thought we could use standard MySql clause :/ .

Comment: Yay for standardization I guess. Thanks for your suggestions nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

You can add another select count(*) query within the parent query to get the total rows.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 25 
    TK_A.DagrapportCivielId,
    TK_A.PartijID,
    TK_S.[ToetsLaatstse105 Algemeen],
    TK_S.ToetsLaatstse105,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting] as tb1
        LEFT JOIN [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16] as Tb2 ON Tb1.DagrapportCivielId = Tb2.DagrapportCivielId) AS total_Rows

FROM
    [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16 Samenvatting] as TK_S  
        LEFT JOIN
    [Toets Korrelverdeling (Algemeen) 4/16] as TK_A ON TK_S.DagrapportCivielId = TK_A.DagrapportCivielId;
```

Comment: sorry for the so much edits, i don't have access in front of me had to format using another sql editor and then change back to access version :)

Comment: Not a problem at all, I genuinely appreciate all the help I can get. I have a question though, should Tbl1 and Tbl2 be replaced by tabelnames? Right now it gives me a syntax error..

Comment: which line do you get the error? try to copy the result and try again

Comment: The query works indeed, thank you for that. I will see if I can use the principle to get the data I want.